# Re-Bind All Controls' Events in Form Load - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

as You know if you cut-paste a control in visual studio you should re-bind all of its events again.

For avoiding such thing, I always re-bind all controls' event in form load like this:

```
    txtIDNum.TextChanging += txtIDNum_TextChanging;
    txtNameLT.TextChanging += txtNameLT_TextChanging;
    txtFamilyLT.TextChanging += txtFamilyLT_TextChanging;
```

in some forms, number of controls are too many and it is very hard to re-bind all events one by one.

I need to write a method to loop through all controls and if there is an event re-bind it. I have a method something like this:

```
   public static void AddEventHandler(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                c.Enter += new EventHandler(EnterEvent);
            else
                AddEventHandler(c);
        }
    }
```

in this case I need to know the type of event and the name of its method to re-bind it. I need this loop to detect all of available control's events and then re-bind them one by one.

Comment: You're doing something wrong if you have to copy and paste that many controls that often.

Comment: sometimes I need to change the design and move some controls in another panel or something similar. In this case I need to re-bind all events :(

Comment: You can drag controls into the new panel without losing the events.

Comment: The problem is more than a drag! My Customer will change its mind every day!!!

Comment: @Stranger Time to look into Agile development practices. If you can't set reasonable expectations and scope with your customer, your life will forever include pain.

Comment: Press down the Control Key as you select controls with your mouse to select more than one.  Or use the View - Other Window - Document Outline tool to move controls to others panels.